# SQL Trigger After Update, Update Field With Value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a trigger that runs after an update is performed. I want the trigger to update that last row that was updated and populate a field called ACTION_TYPE with the string "changed".

Table structure

```
USE BillingUI;

CREATE TABLE tbl8_update_transactions
(
    TID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    TABLE_NUMBER nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    HOLIDAY_DATE nchar(8) NOT NULL,
    FIELD_DESCRIPTION nVARchar(43) NULL,
    ACTION_TYPE nchar(6) NULL,
    HID int,

    FOREIGN KEY (HID) REFERENCES HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE (HID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER tbl8_ins
ON tbl8_update_transactions
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl8_update_transactions
    SET ACTION_TYPE = "change"
    WHERE TID = inserted.TID; 
END
```

I get the following errors:

> invalid column name "change".  - I'm not sure why it thinks change is a column name
>
> the multi-part identifier "inserted.TID" could not be bound.   - I'm unsure of the syntax on this one, trying to perform the update on the row that was just updated.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here: `.... WHERE TID = inserted.TID` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single ticks for the quotes around 'change' and reference INSERTED in the From clause.

```
UPDATE tbl8_update_transactions
SET ACTION_TYPE = 'change'
FROM inserted
WHERE tbl8_update_transactions.TID = inserted.TID;
```

Comment: As this answer alludes to, the trigger happens on the SET, not the individual row.  There are N number of rows in the "inserted" table, not just one.  (unless you are only updating one row, but the logic has to be written for set-based)

Comment: field TID is ambiguous. also I'm only updating one row at a time so that's not a concern.

Comment: whoops, sorry for the ambiguous field.  I've edited it to include the update reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes.

```
SET ACTION_TYPE = 'change'
```

You cannot use the double quote character for values in SQL Server.